# iOS PopoVer NavigationBar don't show BarTintColor

Tags: uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, tint, bartintcolor

In our app we're setting the navigationbar and toolbar color with the following code. With iOS 8.x this is working fine. Recently I have tested the app with iOS 7.x and the colors aren't shown. The bars are transparent and the text has white color (so this worked...)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:167.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:167.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
  [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19.0], NSFontAttributeName,
nil]];
```

I hope somebody could explain me how to solve this. Setting the bars background color is no solution to me because i would use transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to set the color-values manually in the popping-up ViewController again for iOS 7.

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[self.navigationController.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:167.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:167.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```